# How to use comma method to make calculator

Tags: ios, objective-c, calculator

I am making a calculator application now.
Somehow, I could do show the number to display as NSString.
But, I want to do add comma in the number in display.
I searched the method to add ,(comma) in the number, 
but I am not sure how to use the method.
I would like to convert DisplayNumber(without comma) to DisplayNumber(with comma) through
createStringAddedCommaFromInt method. How should I solve ???

*DisplayNumber, firstNumber, secondNumber are int.

```
-(void)show{
        DisplayNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        labelTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", DisplayNumber];
}

- (NSString *)createStringAddedCommaFromInt:(NSInteger)number
{
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[format setGroupingSize:3];

return [format stringForObjectValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to setting the grouping separator, you need to tell `NSNumberFormatter` to use it:

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
format.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; // <<== Don't forget to set the locale
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[format setGroupingSize:3];
format.usesGroupingSeparator = YES; // <<== Add this line
```

This should produce the number with comma separators.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if I want to call the method ? how should I call it ???

Comment: @tomojiro If you would like to use the method syntax rather than the property syntax for the last line, you can rewrite it as `[format setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];`